# how I can show a message to a user through a server in JavaScript (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a small problem. hope you can help me.
I wrote a weather program in NodeJs. when one person wants to search for the weather in their city. they can search here and the app will show them a message. and that is my problem. I can take an input from a user and I can see that input in the command line. here is the Code :

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){
res.render('index');
console.log(req.body.city);
});
```

and this is the other part of the Code but I cannot show the user a message:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
let city = req.body.city;
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apikey}`;
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        res.render('index', { weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again' });
    } else {
        let weather = JSON.parse(body);
        if (weather.main == undefined) {
            res.render('index', { weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again' });
        } else {
            let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees in ${weather.name}!`;
            res.render('index.ejs', { weather: weatherText, error: null });
        }
    }
});

});

app.listen(7000, function(){
    console.log("Hello Boss \nserver is up at port => 7000");

});
```

Note: I have an API key for this aim.

Comment: I have several questions. Do you have EJS setup? I am assuming you used `express --ejs` to create the project.  It might help to see the relevant contents of `index.ejs`. Does Node give any errors? If not, what do you see on the webpage (or, what actually gets rendered)?

Comment: yeah, I have an `index.ejs` file. and I created the all of the files by myself.
I wanna show the user a message but I can't. I wrote the code and you can see it from the second part of this question.

Comment: As I understand it, the first block of code was for initial testing. After that , you replaced it with the second block. Is that correct? If you created the files yourself, make sure you have run `npm install -S ejs` and have `app.set("view engine", "ejs")` in your Node app. I noticed you don't have a GET for `index.ejs`. How does the user load that page for the first time?

Comment: Yeah, i installed ejs with npm and Im sure. And I am exactly sure I added `app.set("view engine ", " ejs");`

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the two parts:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body.city);
let city = req.body.city;
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=imperial&appid=${apikey}`;
request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        res.render('index', { weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again' });
    } else {
        let weather = JSON.parse(body);
        if (weather.main == undefined) {
            res.render('index', { weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again' });
        } else {
            let weatherText = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees in ${weather.name}!`;
            res.render('index.ejs', { weather: weatherText, error: null });
        }
    }
});

});

app.listen(7000, function(){
    console.log("Hello Boss \nserver is up at port => 7000");

});
```

Express.js can only handle one function per URL/request. If you want them both to run, you have to combine them.

Comment: the result is the same as the previous example.

Comment: yeah, I did this before but didn't get an answer.
is there anyone for showing me a way to solve this problem.